# How can you make some text bold programatically in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following: which renders just normal paragraph text. This gets updated fairly quickly. How can I make it so it displays in bold or strong text?

```
$('#header1').text('Year: ' + ui.value);
```

Comment: $('#header1').html('<b>Year: ' + ui.value+'</b>');

Comment: `$('#header1').text('Year: ' + ui.value).css('font-weight','bold');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#header1').text('Year: ' + ui.value).attr("style","font-weight: bold;");
```

or you can also attach some class with this element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('#header1').html( $('<strong/>', {text:'Year: ' + ui.value}) );
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/sxs97xjp/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#header1').html('Year: <b>' + ui.value+ '</b>');
```